# How to sync Android with Rhythmbox?

Tags: sync, android, rhythmbox

I have a Samsung Mini 2 and my wife has an original Samsung 2. I am working with Rhythmbox on 12.10.

I was initially able to sync my Mini with Rhythmbox when I first set up. Then I deleted all the music that I had synced. But now, it will no longer sync with Rhythmbox. Rhythmbox can see it, can poll it, and tell how much space there is etc. But, the sync button is grayed out.

I originally thought that I must have deleted a special file when I deleted the first set of music. However, when testing with my wife's phone, the same problem exists. I can drag and drop from various folders on my PC on to the phone. But it just won't sync via Rhythmbox. I tried the empty file `.is_audio_player` but that had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

For the googlers:

I have read somewhere that Rhythmbox should have at least one music file on the phone. So, copying one file should be enough to make it work.

Comment: That was my solution, just crete a "Music" folder in the "phone" folder of the devide, copy-paste a song, and voila!   My problem was than Rhutymhinox chrashes

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing with my HTC Desire HD. After several unsuccessful attempts I decided to "sync" it manually, that is, I copied a couple of songs in the Music folder. The next time I ran rhythmbox, it gave me the sync option!

I have the `.is_audio_player` file, but I'm not sure if I really need it. One thing for sure is, that it didn't help by itself. I may try again without it and see what happens.

Comment: I had this same issue - I copied one file to my SD card under the "Music" directory and viola...the Sync With Library option was enabled.  I do not have the `.is_audio_player` file.